# Grails get method retrieves old data

Tags: grails, transactions

I have a domain(Owner) which is containing a list of vehicles 
In my service class method i am trying to add some vehicles and remove some vehicles from the Owner's vehicles list.

```
public Owner edit(Long ownerId) {

    Owner owner

    Owner.withTransaction { status ->
        if (ownerId) {
            def vehicle
            owner = Owner.get(ownerId)
            if (owner) {
                // add vehicles
                addVechicleList.each {
                    vehicle = Vehicle.get(new Long(it))
                    if (vehicle) {
                        owner.addToVehicleList(vehicle)
                    }
                }

                // remove vehicles
                removeVehicleList.each {
                    vehicle = Vehicle.get(new Long(it))
                    if (vehicle) {
                        owner.removeFromVehicleList(vehicle)
                    }
                }

                owner?.save(flush: true)

            }
    } // end transaction
    Owner newOwner = Owner.get(ownerId)
    return newOwner // this has the newly added vehicle but not the removed vehicle.
}
```

Domain Classes

```
Owner.groovy

class Owner {
    String ownerName
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [vehicleList: Vehicle]

    static constraints = {
    // some constraints
    }

}

Vehicle.groovy

class Vehicle {
    String vehicleName
    Owner owner
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = Owner
    static hasMany = [owners: Owner]

    static constraints = {
        // some constraints
    }
}
```

I saved the data, I tried with `flush` and without `flush` also, it is containing the removed object.  But if I refresh or place a new request from UI just fetch the owner details then it retrieves the correct values.   After saving the data i tried to see it DB by putting break points. The db got updated but get() method didnt retrieve the correct values.I am using grails 2.2. Am I missing something in the code?? and why it is not taking the updated values??

Comment: Post the domain classes in question.

Comment: @JamesKleeh Updated the question with domain class

Comment: Why does the Vehicle have an `owner` and an `ownerList`?

Comment: I want to maintain a relation like Owner is the one who invested to buy the vehicle and he has given permission to other person who are like sub-owners or users..this is more of business requirement. The problem is why it is not getting the updated result from db??

Answer (score 0):

try changing `Owner` class name to anything else, I had the same problem with `Event` class few days ago :)

Comment: Yeah, actually my class name is not Owner just for example i have given this code